# Error In Displaying Data Records from Database on the console in Json Data format using Ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to display database records to my console in json format but i can't see why my request in json format is not being displayed on my console. There is no error also to guide me where i made a mistake. can someone help me. I use the MVC framework for writing my code. I want to retrieve horse names based on race number from the race table in the database.

here is my home.php

```
<div class="box-body">

    Start creating your amazing application! 

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tables" width="100%">

      <thead>

       <tr>

         <th style="width:10px">#</th>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>Race Number</th>
         <th>Horse Name</th>
         <th>Actions</th>

       </tr> 

      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <?php

          $users = ControllerUsers::ShowallUsersCtr();

          foreach ($users as $key => $value) {

            echo '

              <tr>
                <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                <td>'.$value["id"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["racenumber"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["horsename"].'</td>';


                echo '<td>

                  <div class="btn-group">

                    <button class= "btn btn-primary btnAddRace" RaceNumber="'.$value["racenumber"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUser">Add Horse - Race 1</button>

                  </div>  

                </td>

              </tr>';
          }

        ?>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
```

here is my javascript file code named **users.js**

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnAddRace", function(){

var RaceNumber = $(this).attr("RaceNumber"); // capture the race number from database to the console 
console.log("RaceNumber",RaceNumber);



var data = new FormData();
data.append("RaceNumber",RaceNumber);

$.ajax({

    url: "ajax/users.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(answer){

         console.log("answer", answer); // bring from the database whatever we asked for 


    }

});
```

});

And here is my Ajax file **users.ajax.php**

```
    <?php

require_once "../controllers/users.controller.php";
require_once "../models/users.model.php";

    class AjaxUsers{

        public $RaceNumber;
        public function ajaxEditUser(){

            $item = "racenumber";
            $value = $this->RaceNumber; // value what is selected from the table 

            $answer = ControllerUsers::ctrShowUsers($item, $value); // ask for the controller to show me the race table
            echo json_encode($answer);
        }


    }

    if (isset($_POST["RaceNumber"])) { // if the variable race number comes with information, we can execute all of this

        $edit = new AjaxUsers();
        $edit -> RaceNumber = $_POST["RaceNumber"];
        $edit -> ajaxEditUser();
    }
```

here is my user **controller and model methods**

```
    static public function ctrShowUsers($item, $value){

    $table = "race";

    $answer = UsersModel::MdlShowUsers($table, $item, $value);
    return $answer;
}
static public function MdlShowUsers($table, $item, $value){

        $stmt = Connection::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}
```

Database Picture is here 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTGEt.png)

Comment: You can't really just add random attributes to HTML elements like that - ie `RaceNumber` - you should use a `dataset` attribute instead, like `data-RaceNumber=X` etc

Comment: Your button does not have a `HorseName` attribute but you try to use it in your ajax call

Comment: @RamRaider so you telling me that there is something wrong in my attribute "RaceNumber" in my HTML Elements? suppose i want to write it without using data-, how to write it without any error?

Comment: It is not a genuine attribute so you should avoid doing this... but I see you have now modified your javascript to remove the missing HorseName attribute. Why not use `data-HorseNumber`??

Comment: @RamRaider lets say if I use 'data-RaceNumber="'.value["racenumber"].'"' how should i declare this 'RaceNumber' class in my javascript file so that i can send this value to my sql query via my controller?

Comment: I would guess like this: `data.append("RaceNumber",$(this).attr("data-RaceNumber"));`?

Comment: excellent news - good luck